# Windows 10 Can't open files on double click, right click or 'open with' anymore

Tags: windows-10

I use Windows 10 and since a couple of days I can't open files any more. I cannot open them by double clicking, right clicking them and choosing 'open', or right clicking them and choosing 'open with'. This does not seem program-specific, meaning no option selected from the 'open with' menu will open the file any more.

The only option I can open files with is by opening the software in question first and then selecting the open dialogue from within the program. For example, I open Word, then choose the open file option within Word which in turns opens the File Explorer and I can choose and open a .docx file then. This works without problems but is very time consuming.

Besides the Windows File Explorer I have installed another one with the same result.

Any help is much appreciated!

Edit: Actually this might have something to do with Sophos (antivirus program) as it mostly seems to affect files I download from the Internet. If anybody knows of an option I need to toggle, please let me know.

Comment: Take an example file, whitelist it in Sophos, restart and see if that works. You do not really need two AV on Windows 10. Windows Defender is top notch and works well in Windows 10 and 11.

Comment: Sophos is probably the problem here.. I would love to hear what happens if you do what @John requests in his comment.